# angular 6 :- Reactive form value not changing

Tags: angular6

I have created a dynamic page in angular 6 with form group controls.
How can i change form  group control value?
I'm adding data in a textbox like `$(#id).val("myval")` in some scenario.
So while doing like this formgroup control value not changing,
can anyone give suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question related to the words `doing liking` as it's not clear enough what you mean or a just a wrong expression. Also adding some code could be helpful as your short example code is too short. Perhaps the site [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is helping you. Thanks!

Comment: The code you have posted looks like you are using jQuery, which is wrong if you are using Angular 6. Instead you should take a look at this https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Use FormControl.prototype.setValue() not jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are accessing it from the component, then you can access all the form values through "this.FORMNAME.value" where "FORMNAME" if the name you used in the constructor.

> Try: this.FORMNAME.controls.CONTROLNAME.setValue("myval");